# Raspberry RFSniffer read output with python

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run the RFSniffer process to listen for incoming 433mhz signals.

If I run the process, it just outputs the values from the 433mhz receiver. I want to read this output with Python so that I can do specific actions.

I've found many ways to run it and get the output with Python but that where commands that are self terminated (`ls -ial`). The RFSniffer process runs until you stop it manually.

This is what I have now (not working):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess, time, os, sys

cmd = ["sudo", "/home/pi/433Utils/RPi_utils/RFSniffer"]

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print line,
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working? Is it that you only get a partial output of the command? What is the output of the command like when you run it directly (outside of Python)?

Comment: I'm not getting any output, when i run out outside python output is:
Received 14446784
Received 14446640
Received 14446784
Received 14446784
Received 14446784

Comment: you can also edit the RFSniffer.cpp and recompile it, so it writes directly into a file or in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution should work:

```
os.system("sudo /home/pi/433Utils/RPi_utils/RFSniffer >output.txt & pkill --signal SIGINT RFSniffer")
f = open("output.txt","r")
readf = f.read()
for line in readf:
    print line,
#close file
if f.closed == "False":
    f.close()
```

You could put it in a while loop to constantly scan until a parameter has been found.

This is the only way I have come across to which you can output a realtime scan (infinite and non stopping, not like ls -l) to a file and then read the values.

Here is an example of one of my realtime scans using bluetooth:

```
sensortag=0
while sensortag != "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0":
    #call the command and write to scan.txt file and then fill the process.
    #loop to find if the MAC address given is available
    os.system("hcitool lescan> scan.txt & pkill --signal SIGINT hcitool")
    scan = open("scan.txt","r")
    readscan = scan.read()
    if "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0" in readscan:
        print "SensorTag found."
        sensortag = "B4:99:4C:64:33:E0"
```

Comment: Not working :-( syntax error:   File "test2.py", line 8
    for line in readf
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry i missed a : after the for statement. I have updated the code. Typo error my bad.

Comment: Script starts but is not writing any data to output.txt also if i run the command with >output.txt direct in the terminal. :(

Comment: I changed the RFSniffer.cpp file so that it logs to a file and now its working, thanks for helping me on the way.

Answer (score 1):

If it fits your needs you can do it the other way round. I let my python script be called from the RFSniffer passing in the signals as arguments.

My python script looks similar to the following:

```
import sys, getopt
import uuid

fileEnding = "txt"
fileFolder = "./sniffed"

def main(argv):
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"s:")

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-s':
            filename = fileFolder + "/" + str(uuid.uuid4()) + "." + fileEnding
            with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
                outfile.write(arg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Now you need to edit RFSniffer.cpp to call your python-script after each received signal. Following snippet concats all signal-codes received in a short frame of time as one press on your remote sometimes results in more than one signal-code. Thus your python script is called not per signal but per button-press. 
I am no CPP-developer so excuse my clumsy approach on this (but hey, it does its job ;))

```
//[...]
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
//[...]
while(1) {
          int count = 0;
          std::string signals;
          signals = "";

          while (count < 10000) {
              if (mySwitch.available()) {
                    int value = mySwitch.getReceivedValue();

                    if (value == 0) {
                        printf("Unknown encoding\n");
                    } else {
                        std::string signal;
                        std::stringstream signalStream;
                        signalStream << value;
                        signal = signalStream.str();

                        if (signals.length() > 0) {
                            signals.append(",");
                        }
                        else {
                            // first receive, so reset timeframe here
                            count = 0;
                        }
                        signals.append(signal);
                        printf("Received %s\n", signal.c_str() );
                    }
                    mySwitch.resetAvailable();
              }
              usleep(50);
              count += 1;
          }
          if (signals.length() > 0) {
            std::string command;
            command.append("python3 /home/pi/your_script.py -s ");
            command.append(signals);
            printf("Call %s\n", command.c_str());
            system(command.c_str());
          }
      }
      //[...]
```

So what it does is do loop 10k times looking for new "ReceivedValue" and waits for 50 microseconds. You can adjust these parameters if you want. This means one timeframe is at least half a second long and should cover all signals belonging to a single button press on your remote. These one to many signal-codes are passed in as comma-separated values to your python-script (argument -s code1,code2,code3). Do whatever you want with it inside your script. 
Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

As @user1232869 didn't share how he did to modify `RFSniffer.cpp` and as it costs me a bit of time because I'm not familiar at all with C++, I'm sharing it :). You just need to add the three bold lines to your file.

```
if (value == 0) {
      printf("Unknown encoding");
    } else {    

      printf("Received %i\n", mySwitch.getReceivedValue() );
      // These lines are the lines which interest you! :)
      FILE* pFile = fopen("/home/pi/logs.txt", "a");
      fprintf(pFile, "%i\n",mySwitch.getReceivedValue());
      fclose(pFile);
    }

    mySwitch.resetAvailable();
```

And then you can use the answer of @Jonathan Davies properly because the `>output.txt` also failed on my Pi.

Answer (score -1):

I used a python library called pi-switch that provides a wrapper around the rc-switch C++ library.
This library can be found at https://github.com/lexruee/pi-switch-python

rc-switch is the library that RFSniffer uses, so using pi-switch allows you to listen to 433mhz signals from python.

I am using it to detect when a wireless doorbell has been pressed.

Comment: Even though a link to a page is useful, it would also be interesting to know the usage of such wrapper in the context of the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks, I've amended my answer.